# C++ error 'Undefined reference to Class::Function()

Tags: c++, oop, undefined, header-files, undefined-reference

I was just wondering if anybody can help me with this and I am new to C++ and I am having a problem when I am separating the classes into different files.

The error I am getting when I compile the SepMain.cpp file is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cciHobHn.o: in function `main':
SepMain.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `Sep::Sep()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error I am getting when I compile the Sep.cpp file is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error I am getting when I compile the Sep.h file is:

```
bash: /home/ishan/Coding/C++/Learn/tempCodeRunnerFile: Permission denied
```

so my codes have three files:

Sep.cpp

```
#include "Sep.h"        
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   
Sep::Sep()
{
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
}
```

Sep.h

```
#ifndef SEP_H
#define SEP_H

class Sep
{
    public:
        Sep();
};

#endif
```

SepMain.cpp

```
#include "Sep.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Sep ir;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One does not execute a .cpp or a .h file, instead one compiles the c++ files into an executable and executes _that_.

Comment: You say that like you compile each file separately and try to execute that. Then - of course - SepMain.cpp does not know the constructor definition and Sep.cpp does not have a main function. You have to compile both files and link them together to form an actual application. Your compiler should be able to do that

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes can you tell how to compile both files and link them together to form an actual application

Comment: Unfortunately not, that stuff is compiler-dependent. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes The compiler is  gcc version 9.3.0 and I am using it in ubuntu

Comment: I don't know much about that, so I'm going to refer you [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/tutorials/separate/separate.html)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Thanks man for telling me to compile both files together  and I did some more googling and I found out how to fix this problem 
In the terminal I had to type:
g++ SepMain.cpp Sep,cpp  -std=c++11
./a.out